# How to clone -> reverse -> and prependTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, reverse

I have a list of element e.g.: `.title`, I'm cloning them out and append them to a container, but the order is reversed from prependTo`.

How do I put these cloned element to an array and reverse it before prepending them?

For example, for each `.title` clone it, and `prependTo` `.container`, and wrap it with `li`:

```
$('.title').each(function() {
     $this.clone()
          .prependTo('.container')
          .wrap('<li></li>')
});
```

Comment: what do you want to sort? index of element? text inside the element? what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="title">A</li>
    <li class="title">B</li>
    <li class="title">C</li>
    <li class="title">D</li>
    <li class="title">E</li>
</ul>

<ul class="container">        
</ul>
```

Use this jQuery to add them to the `.container` element:

```
$('.title').each(function() {
    $('.container')
        .append($(this).clone());
});
```

If you want to reverse the order, then use `.prepend` instead of `.append`.

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/y8Aub/ if you want to see it in action.

Comment: yup, i'm stupid, should of use AppendTo instead of prependTo lol

Comment: Nope, I've done things like that too!  Sometimes you get so focused on a problem that you can't see the answer that's sitting right in front of you ;p